# Swift memory leak in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, view, segue

I followed this tutorial to create an app that displays multiple views, however I discovered that I have a memory leak.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dulio-denis/ios-quick-read-implementi_4_b_6923788.html

It seems that every time I open the child view, return to the previous view, then open the child view again, the allocated memory will increase critically.

I think this is because the child view has been cached. What is the proper way to avoid memory leaks when creating an app with multiple views?

Comment: show us some code. how do you dismiss/close the child views?

Comment: All code are in the tutorial. After embed navigation controller to the main view, i have the back button on the navigator on every views. Tap on it and i get back to the main view.